# Attributes in service class in Windows Workflow Foundation services

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I've been incorporating some security features in my WCF services placing some customized attributes that implement IServiceBehavior in my service classes. For example:

```
[AuthenticationBehavior()]
public class BRService1 : ServiceBase, IBRService1
```

Where

```
public class AuthenticationBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
...
}
```

But I need to do the same to some WWF services, although I don't a have a explicit service class where I can add the attributes.

Do you know a way that I can do the same in the Workflow services?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a lot of research and test I found an answer in this post:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9b45eaf-c8e2-444c-819d-e448868e68bb/using-workflow-extensions-contextgetextension-in-iishosted-workflows?forum=wfprerelease

Summary:

1. Create a wrapper class for the service behavior class inherited from BehaviorExtensionElement:

   ```
   public class AuthenticationElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
   {
       public override Type BehaviorType
       {
           get { return typeof(AuthenticationBehavior); }
       }

       protected override object CreateBehavior()
       {
           return new AuthenticationBehavior();
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the config file of the service exposing the workflows, in the  section add:

2.1 An extension for the BehaviorExtensionElement created before:

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="authenticationBehaviorExt"
         type="Security.AuthenticationElement, Security"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

2.2 A service behavior:

```
<behavior name="authenticationBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
  <authenticationBehaviorExt />
</behavior>
```

2.3 Add the serviceBehavior to the workflow service definition

```
<service name="WFService" behaviorConfiguration="authenticationBehavior">
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttp_Workflow" contract="IWFService" />
</service>
```

3. Enjoy.